# Como mudar valores do eixo x (não o título do eixo) no "seasonplot"?

Tags: r

Na função  `seasonplot` do pacote `forecast`, como eu faço para trocar os nomes do eixo "x"?

Usei o argumento "xlab", mas ele só da nomes ao eixo, eu preciso mudar as escalas do eixo.

*Ex: Lá aparece os dias da semana em inglês, preciso colocar em português e mudar a ordem em que eles aparecem!*

Comment: Mas qual o problema com o xlab?

Comment: Ele só da nomes ao eixo, eu preciso mudar as escalas do eixo, ex: Lá aparece os dias da semana em inglês, preciso colocar em português e mudar a ordem em que eles aparecem !

Comment: Rafael, quando for assim, coloque toda a informação necessária na sua pergunta, era impossível adivinhar o que você queria. Dê uma olhada aqui http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/825#825

Comment: Editei a sua pergunta para ilustrar como seria.

Comment: Desculpa, achei q tinha ficado claro, mas não foi o caso !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olhando o código da função `seasonplot` do pacote `forecast`, nota-se que esses valores não estão como argumentos e sim dentro do código. Dessa forma, uma solução seria você alterar essas partes do código que estão em inglês para o português:

```
seasonplot2 <- function (x, s, season.labels = NULL, year.labels = FALSE, year.labels.left = FALSE, 
                         type = "o", main, ylab = "", xlab = NULL, col = 1, labelgap = 0.1, 
                         ...) 
{
  mes <- c("Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", 
           "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez")
  if (missing(main)) 
    main = paste("Seasonal plot:", deparse(substitute(x)))
  if (missing(s)) 
    s = frequency(x)
  if (s <= 1) 
    stop("Frequency must be > 1")
  tsx <- x
  if (start(x)[2] > 1) 
    x <- c(rep(NA, start(x)[2] - 1), x)
  x <- c(x, rep(NA, s - length(x)%%s))
  Season <- rep(c(1:s, NA), length(x)/s)
  xnew <- rep(NA, length(x))
  xnew[!is.na(Season)] <- x
  if (s == 12) {
    labs <- mes
    xLab <- "Mês"
  }
  else if (s == 4) {
    labs <- mes[c(1, 4, 7, 10)]
    xLab <- "Trimestre"
  }
  else if (s == 7) {
    labs <- c("Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", 
              "Sat")
    xLab <- "Dia"
  }
  else {
    labs <- NULL
    xLab <- "Season"
  }
  if (is.null(xlab)) 
    xlab <- xLab
  if (is.null(season.labels)) 
    season.labels <- labs
  if (year.labels) 
    xlim <- c(1 - labelgap, s + 0.4 + labelgap)
  else xlim <- c(1 - labelgap, s)
  if (year.labels.left) 
    xlim[1] <- 0.4 - labelgap
  plot(Season, xnew, xaxt = "n", xlab = xlab, type = type, 
       ylab = ylab, main = main, xlim = xlim, col = 0, ...)
  nn <- length(Season)/s
  col <- rep(col, nn)[1:nn]
  for (i in 0:(nn - 1)) lines(Season[(i * (s + 1) + 1):((s + 
                                                           1) * (i + 1))], xnew[(i * (s + 1) + 1):((s + 1) * (i + 
                                                                                                                1))], type = type, col = col[i + 1], ...)
  if (year.labels) {
    idx <- which(Season[!is.na(xnew)] == s)
    year <- time(tsx)[idx]
    text(x = rep(s + labelgap, length(year)), y = tsx[idx], 
         labels = paste(c(trunc(year))), adj = 0, ..., col = col[1:length(idx)])
  }
  if (year.labels.left) {
    idx <- which(Season[!is.na(xnew)] == 1)
    year <- time(tsx)[idx]
    if (min(idx) > 1) 
      col <- col[-1]
    text(x = rep(1 - labelgap, length(year)), y = tsx[idx], 
         labels = paste(c(trunc(year))), adj = 1, ..., col = col[1:length(idx)])
  }
  if (is.null(labs)) 
    axis(1, ...)
  else axis(1, labels = season.labels, at = 1:s, ...)
}
```

Exemplo:

```
seasonplot2(woolyrnq)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]